# How do I use the VFPOLEDB Provider to make use of the .NDX/.CDX indexing when I read a huge FoxPro .DBF?

Tags: c#, sql, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I am writing a .NET application in C# that reads a FoxPro .DBF using the Visual FoxPro OLE DB provider (VFPOLEDB.1).

The problem is the .DBF is 900MB, so a simple read takes way too long, compared to the instantaneous reading from FoxPro (we use the DOS FoxPro). The difference between the provider and and a native FoxPro search is that I assume FoxPro makes use of the indexing files (we use .CDX and .NDX) and the provider does a kind of linear search with the given SQL statement.

```
public DataTable getData(string refNum = "TESTREFNUM")
{

    DataTable result = new DataTable();

    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
            "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\\PATH\\TO\\DBFFILES\\;Exclusive=No");

        connection.Open();

        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            string mySQL = "SELECT DP_PRO, DP_FILE, DP_NUM"
                + "FROM DISPATCH"                           // 900MB dispatch.dbf
                + "WHERE DP_PRO LIKE '%" + refNum + "%'";

            OleDbCommand MyQuery = new OleDbCommand(mySQL, connection);
            OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter(MyQuery);

            DA.Fill(result);

            connection.Close();
        }
    return result;
}
```

So from my research, I've seen more support for .CDX files than .NDX files, which is fine. But how do I set the OleDBConnection to make use of the indexing, besides the default slow search through the file?

Are there any changes I have to make to the SQL statement? Or the provider? Or settings to change on the DBF file? From research, I've also found out that .CDX references are in the headers of the .DBF file, so it shouldn't be a problem for the provider to know which .CDX files are associated.

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated. I'm a recent grad with no FoxPro experience. :p

Comment: Is your question related to using `.NDX` or `.CDX`. The former must be manually opened, and IIRC isn't used when using SQL queries against the DB. The latter is auto-opened when the database is opened, and the appropriate index is automatically used (if it exists) when a SQL query is executed. (Your title mentions both .NDX/.CDX. It's relevant to the question to know which one specifically is being used for the database you're using in your SQL query when that query is run.)

Comment: I am able to set indices in either .NDX or .CDX onto the database, my question was whether Ole DB had support for either and whether I can make use of them. From the answers and research, I've seen that .CDX has better support and is used automatically.

Comment: Also, to answer your question, the database I am working with has both .NDX and .CDX indices with some overlap between which fields they are indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the compound index (the CDX) you want to make sure your queries are Rushmore-optimised. That's all you need to do - if a CDX is present for the table in question (as indicated in the header of the DBF) then it will be automatically used. Looking at the example above, the assumption therefore is that there is no index tag on the field DP_PRO.

Comment: Oh wow! I just realized that the two wildcards '%' in the SQL statement were what slowed the search. It limits to what the user can put in, as they have to be exact values now, but if it makes the program faster, we'll go with that. Thanks Alan.

Comment: That's odd, since queries of that type *should* be optimisable but you might need to construct the index a certain way. Mark it as answered eh? :)

Answer (score -2):

VFPOLEDB provider doesn't support indexes at all.

Comment: Do you have anything to back this claim up?  Alan B's answer and attached comments indicate otherwise.  (and INDEX is even on the [list of supported OLE DB commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80x51c04%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Just try to create an index via SQL & VFPOLEDB. However, [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/770c9e5a-8c42-4cdb-bfbb-6894d80c12b3/how-to-tell-if-a-column-has-an-index-using-vfpoledb?forum=visualfoxprogeneral) workaround would be useful for you.

Comment: While it may be difficult to *create* an index via VFPOLEDB, that's not the same as "doesn't support indexes at all"; indexes that already exist can be used for optimizing SQL queries, for instance.

Comment: Thanks Ken, I'll check this out again.