# Running queries on DBF files using OLEDB(VFPOLEDB) is too slow

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro

I am working on an interface to display data from DBF files in a WinForm application.
I started on using OdbcConnection. Notwithstanding it worked, due to certain restriction of Visual FoxPro driver (subqueries are not supported), I switched on using OLEDB(VFPOLEDB). Now I am able to run complex queries but new difficulties appeared that have to be solved. The problem is that these queries are TOO slow. Slower 100 times than expected.

Below is a code for the demonstration.
There is a DBF table ‘PROD’. An indexed field PRICE_N is used in a Where clause of a query. The table is on the same PC where the application is running on. As you can see the spent time on running a query via ODBC(Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver) and OLEDB(VFPOLEDB) is varied dramatically.

```
            TimeSpan timeSpanODBC;
        DateTime timeODBC = DateTime.Now;

        OdbcConnection odbcConnection = new OdbcConnection(@"Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=C:\Users\Vakshul\Documents\dbfs;Exclusive=No;Collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;");
        odbcConnection.Open();
        OdbcCommand odbcCommand = new OdbcCommand("SELECT utk_ved FROM prod WHERE (price_n='641857')", odbcConnection);
        odbcCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        timeSpanODBC = DateTime.Now - timeODBC;
        double timeOdbcEqual = timeSpanODBC.TotalMilliseconds;
        System.Console.WriteLine("Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - {0}", timeOdbcEqual.ToString());


        timeODBC = DateTime.Now;

        odbcCommand = new OdbcCommand("SELECT utk_ved FROM prod WHERE (price_n like'641857')", odbcConnection);
        odbcCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        timeSpanODBC = DateTime.Now - timeODBC;
        double timeOdbcLike = timeSpanODBC.TotalMilliseconds;
        System.Console.WriteLine("Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - {0}", timeOdbcLike.ToString());

        TimeSpan timeSpanOLEDB;
        DateTime timeOLEDB = DateTime.Now;

        OleDbConnection oleDbCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\Users\Vakshul\Documents\dbfs;Collating Sequence=MACHINE;Mode=Read");
        oleDbCon.Open();
        OleDbCommand oleDbcommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT utk_ved FROM prod WHERE (price_n = '641857')", oleDbCon);
        oleDbcommand.ExecuteScalar();
        timeSpanOLEDB = DateTime.Now - timeOLEDB;
        double timeOLEDBEqual = timeSpanOLEDB.TotalMilliseconds;
        System.Console.WriteLine("Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - {0}", timeOLEDBEqual.ToString());

        timeOLEDB = DateTime.Now;

        oleDbcommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT utk_ved FROM prod WHERE (price_n like '641857')", oleDbCon);
        oleDbcommand.ExecuteScalar();
        timeSpanOLEDB = DateTime.Now - timeOLEDB;
        double timeOLEDLike = timeSpanOLEDB.TotalMilliseconds;
        System.Console.WriteLine("Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - {0}", timeOLEDLike.ToString());

        System.Console.WriteLine("ODBC is faster than OLEDB {0} times using '=' to compare", Math.Round(timeOLEDBEqual / timeOdbcEqual, 0));
        System.Console.WriteLine("ODBC is faster than OLEDB {0} times using 'Like' to compare", Math.Round(timeOLEDBEqual / timeOdbcEqual, 0));
```

Console, after the first run:

```
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 5,0006
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 3,5005
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 1630,207
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 1755,2228
ODBC is faster than OLEDB 326 times using '=' to compare
ODBC is faster than OLEDB 326 times using 'Like' to compare

Console, after the second run:
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 4,5006
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 4,5005
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 1526,1938
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 1595,2026
ODBC is faster than OLEDB 339 times using '=' to compare
ODBC is faster than OLEDB 339 times using 'Like' to compare

Console, after the third run:
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 4,0005
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 3,0004
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 1449,184
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 1451,1843
ODBC is faster than OLEDB 362 times using '=' to compare
ODBC is faster than OLEDB 362 times using 'Like' to compare

Console, after the fourth run:
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 3,5004
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 4,5006
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 1475,6874
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 1621,2059
ODBC is faster than OLEDB 422 times using '=' to compare
ODBC is faster than OLEDB 422 times using 'Like' to compare
```

In this sample an indexed field PRICE_N is included in a Where clause of the query.
I also tested the same query including a non-indexed field in a Where clause instead of an indexed one. The result was the same ~ 1400 – 1600 milliseconds.
I have the impression that in a case of OLEDB(VFPOLEDB) indices are not used.
I am not satisfied with the result and I need the indices to be used.

If someone has any suggestions I will be very grateful.

Comment: Have you seen [this article](http://www.vfug.org/newsletters/oledbproviderwaystochangesettings.htm)?

Comment: Thanks, @stuartd. I haven't seen it before, so I've read it thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks, @stuartd. I haven't seen it before, so I've read it thoroughly. I tried to use TABLEVALIDATE=0 but to no avail. Nothing has changed. The speed is so low that it's difficult to bealive. I guess indices are not used. But why so? I even deployed a virtual machine, installed all the needed SW there, but to the same result :(

Comment: So there are CDX indices defined on the columns? Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25690157/how-do-i-use-the-vfpoledb-provider-to-make-use-of-the-ndx-cdx-indexing-when-i)?

Comment: Also, you say you are using the VFPOLEDB driver because the native driver doesn't support subqueries: I remember this being a pain back when I was a VFP developer (which was back when the year number had a lot of 'nines' in it) and although this was a pain it could be worked around with creative use of outer joins. Do you _really_ need subqueries? (I've retagged your question with `Visual-FoxPro` in the hope that you may get help from someone who still uses it)

Comment: Yes, I’ve seen the discussion you referred. They agreed that CDX(in my case there are CDX and FPT files) indices will be automatically used. But I don’t think indices are used in my case. You ask if I really need subqueries. Unfortunately the construction “select t.* from (select …) as t” won’t work. Without that it will be too complex for me to get what I want. For the time being I drop the result of my subqueries to SQL server’s #temp tables and work with them there but I’d like to get back to VFPOLEDB and work with it. Thank you for your time, stuartd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sergiy,
I may have a solution for you:

```
string sqlEq = "SELECT utk_ved FROM prod WHERE Price_N = '641857'";
string sqlLike = "SELECT utk_ved FROM prod WHERE Price_N like '641857'";

TimeSpan timeSpanODBC;
DateTime timeODBC = DateTime.Now;

OdbcConnection odbcConnection = new OdbcConnection(@"Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=C:\Users\Vakshul\Documents\dbfs;Exclusive=No;Collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;");
odbcConnection.Open();
OdbcCommand odbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(sqlEq, odbcConnection);
odbcCommand.ExecuteScalar();
timeSpanODBC = DateTime.Now - timeODBC;
double timeOdbcEqual = timeSpanODBC.TotalMilliseconds;
System.Console.WriteLine("Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - {0}", timeOdbcEqual.ToString());


timeODBC = DateTime.Now;

odbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(sqlLike, odbcConnection);
odbcCommand.ExecuteScalar();
timeSpanODBC = DateTime.Now - timeODBC;
double timeOdbcLike = timeSpanODBC.TotalMilliseconds;
System.Console.WriteLine("Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - {0}", timeOdbcLike.ToString());

TimeSpan timeSpanOLEDB;
DateTime timeOLEDB = DateTime.Now;

OleDbConnection oleDbCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\Users\Vakshul\Documents\dbfs;Collating Sequence=MACHINE;Mode=Read");
oleDbCon.Open();
new OleDbCommand("set enginebehavior 80", oleDbCon).ExecuteNonQuery();
OleDbCommand oleDbcommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlEq, oleDbCon);
oleDbcommand.ExecuteScalar();
timeSpanOLEDB = DateTime.Now - timeOLEDB;
double timeOLEDBEqual = timeSpanOLEDB.TotalMilliseconds;
System.Console.WriteLine("Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - {0}", timeOLEDBEqual.ToString());

timeOLEDB = DateTime.Now;

oleDbcommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlLike, oleDbCon);

oleDbcommand.ExecuteScalar();
timeSpanOLEDB = DateTime.Now - timeOLEDB;
double timeOLEDLike = timeSpanOLEDB.TotalMilliseconds;
System.Console.WriteLine("Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - {0}", timeOLEDLike.ToString());
```

Note this line ***on the same connection***:

```
new OleDbCommand("set enginebehavior 80", oleDbCon).ExecuteNonQuery();
```

That wouldn't affect your results but get what you want. Off the top of my head, the only place that it may affect is the "group by" queries. Thinking you wouldn't write the group by queries in the old buggy VFP way you should be safe.

My timings without "Set EngineBehavior 80":

```
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 4.0002
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 1.0001
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 352.0201
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 659.0377
```

and with "Set EngineBehavior 80":

```
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 3.0001
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 2.0002
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 15.0008
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 3.0002
```

Comment: again you are very helpful. Indeed, using data engine compatibility with Visual FoxPro 8.0 allows to avoid a decrease in query's speed. It also allows to run queries like "select t.* from (select ...) as t". Hope I'll be able to run more complex queries. Your help is really invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering...  is your "Price_n" column a NUMERIC or a STRING column.  If numeric, then I wonder if the VFP OleDb is trying to convert all your numerics to a STRING equivalent for the testing instead of converting the quoted string to the numeric equivalent of the Price_n data type as I would expect the natural index to be based on.

If so, try testing and changing all your WHERE clauses respectively to

WHERE price_n = 641857

WHERE price_n Like 641857

but if Numeric based column, then the Like really would not be applicable because a number is a number and not like a partial string match like

```
"1" LIKE "1"
"1" LIKE "10"
"1" LIKE "19302"... etc where they all start with a same value
```

Comment: Hi DRapp,
‘price_n’ is a STRING column. That’s why quotes as used in a Where clause:
 WHERE (price_n='641857').
The reason I used LIKE in this test was simply a hope that using it might add some clarity at what’s going on.
I ought to have added I did my tests on Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012, .Net Framework 4.5

Comment: @SergiyVakshul, do you have an index on PRICE_N? and that is the first column in a possible multiple key index expression?  I have used VFP OleDb in the past and had quite fast queries.. even under .Net 3.5 and 4.  For production though, I would strongly suggest parameterizing the queries though.

Comment: I do have an index on PRICE_N. There are several indices on the table and one of them is on PRICE_N. This index isn’t multiple. It’s just an index for one column. As to parameterizing a query I checked it as well – the result is the same – too slow.

Comment: @SergiyVakshul, Just one final thought... is the database static (ie: not changing content and a fixed data that will not get read/write by the web-based content, but maybe populated by other means...  If so, and you make the tables/cdx files as READ-ONLY permissions for the web-based / C# querying, the O/S does not need to do any overhead on any possible locking even though it is just querying anyhow.  (also, how large is the table)

Comment: "1" LIKE "10" is FALSE, no? LIKE is implicityly ANSI ON and behaves as if you used ==.

Answer (score 0):

@Sergiy,
There is a big difference on what you are doing. ODBC driver doesn't exist for versions after VFP6 (namely 2.5 or 2.6 was the last package containing ODBC driver). IOW ODBC supports VFP6 engine only. OTOH VFPOLEDB supports VFP9 engine (and all those added SQL capabilities with bells and whistles).

Between those engines, there were an issue making the queries slow on text fields:
If OS codepage is different than the table's codepage and the search is being done on an index whose expression is of character type. Then it doesn't use the index but do a table scan. This "bug" surfaced after the initial release of VFP9 and not corrected AFAIK.

As per the = vs like, like is implicitly ANSI so behaves like < g > using == operator (exact match). With =, if ANSI is OFF you get partial matches as true.

PS: VFPOLEDB, even after correction of the codepages, is slightly slower but negligible.

Here are my timings with your code, on a test table with 1,000,000 rows:

```
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 41.0023
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 0
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 68.0038
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 2.0002
ODBC is faster than OLEDB 2 times using '=' to compare
ODBC is faster than OLEDB 2 times using 'Like' to compare
```

And these are the timings after second run:

```
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 1
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 1.0001
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 3.0001
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 0
ODBC is faster than OLEDB 3 times using '=' to compare
ODBC is faster than OLEDB 3 times using 'Like' to compare
```

Answer (score 0):

@Cetin Basoz,

> Between those engines, there were an issue making the queries slow on
>   text fields: If OS codepage is different than the table's codepage and
>   the search is being done on an index whose expression is of character
>   type. Then it doesn't use the index but do a table scan. This "bug"
>   surfaced after the initial release of VFP9 and not corrected AFAIK.

You hit the crux of the matter!

I didn’t know about that peculiarity. I decided to check if that is really so. If your assumption was right the reason for low speed was that the code pages of DBF file and my OS were different. To test that I installed Visual Fox Pro 9(I have never dealt with it before) and transferred all the data to a new table. Then I opened the table in Table Designer and created a regular index on PRICE_N field. Thus the code pages of the new table and my OS became the same.

Then I run the test again. The result changed dramatically.

After the first run:

```
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 12,5016
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 3,5005
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 20,0025
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 3,0004
ODBC is faster than OLEDB 2 times using '=' to compare
ODBC is faster than OLEDB 2 times using 'Like' to compare
```

After the second run:

```
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 3,0004
Time spent via ODBC(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 2,5003
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using '=' to compare - 11,0014
Time spent via OLEDB(milliseconds) using 'Like' to compare - 3,5005
ODBC is faster than OLEDB 4 times using '=' to compare
ODBC is faster than OLEDB 4 times using 'Like' to compare
```

Thanks, Cetin Basoz. The comment was awesome :)

Even though I am not allowed to change the code page of a production DBF file, at least now I can cast off a burden with a sense of relief when I know what’s happening.